# Prevent array from emptying on refresh in Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, page-refresh

I have an array in my Meteor application. Every time I refresh the page, the array empties (verified using `console.log(array.length)` in `Meteor.startup()`). What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent Javascript from initializing on a page refresh.

All you can do, is initialize the array on page load.

You really only have three choices on page refresh:

1. initialize the array to some default data,
2. get the values from a mongo query, or
3. get the values from browser localStorage

The actual problem in this code is not saving the data somewhere more permanent, like the mongodb or localStorage, so you can fetch it when user hits refresh or accidentally closes his browser.

Comment: A session variable would survive a hot code push, but not a manual refresh.